# What is the word for the kind of thing that legal laws can apply to?

Tags: single-word-requests, legalese

I know this question title is awkward, so let me explain by example:

> The word "law" means different things in different contexts. You have
>   the "*laws* of natural science" (e.g. the law of energy conservation) versus the "*laws* of __" (e.g. shoplifting is against the law).

I have trouble filling in the blank. *States*? *Nations*? *Jurisdictions*? Am I on the right track at all by thinking about governmental jargon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the word you're looking for is [jurisprudence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jurisprudence) which is defined as:

> The philosophy, science, and study of law and decisions based on the interpretation thereof.

Quoting from ["Natural Law And Laws of Nature in Early Modern Europe: Jurisprudence, Theology, Moral And Natural Philosophy"](http://books.google.com/books?id=1I5icnBY0XgC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22laws+of+jurisprudence%22+legal&source=bl&ots=yVbEj6_5uN&sig=2FSy1gN2LfP7XqjfBraBU2Fw0vk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O3UfUMq4CMitrAfD1IEQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22laws%20of%20jurisprudence%22%20legal&f=false):

> From then on, the basic underlying differences between **the laws of jurisprudence** and *the laws of natural science* could no longer be overlooked.

Comment: Aha, I knew there was a word for this. Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, will accept your answer when the timer lets me.

Answer (score 3):

I would generally call this the "laws of the land" but this is not a formal term.